# Sum a MySQL column and keep others

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT     a.datacadastro, <br>
       e.nome AS solicitante, <br>
       b.nome AS servico, <br>
       d.valorservico, <br>
       c.idlabpedido, <br>
       f.dente <br>
FROM       labpedido a <br>
INNER JOIN labservico b <br>
INNER JOIN labpedidoservico c
ON         c.idlabservico = b.id
AND        a.id = c.idlabpedido <br>
INNER JOIN labservicovalor d 
ON         ( 
                  c.idlabservico = d.idlabservico) <br>
INNER JOIN usuarios e
ON         (
                  a.usuarioinsert = e.id) <br>
INNER JOIN labpedidoservicodente f 
ON         ( 
                  a.id = f.idlabpedido)<br>
where      b.status='1' <br>
ORDER BY   a.datacadastro<br>
```

it returns all the parameters I need, except for the column "valorServico".

I want this one to be the sum of all the rows.
143.00 is the price for each "dente", since I have 6 rows of it, it should return me 858.00 (143.00 * 6).

What is the best way to achieve that?

It returns:

dataCadastro  |  solicitante   |   servico    |    valorServico    |   idLabpedido   |   dente
2017-01-30      rodrigo        4            143.00           518                13
2017-01-30      rodrigo        4            143.00           518                14
2017-01-30      rodrigo        4            143.00           518                15

Comment: Please review how to ask a question on SO. The code should be in the question; we shouldn't have to go elsewhere to find out what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that.

Comment: link to [ask] for your reference

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way will be something like:

```
select a.dataCadastro, 
e.nome as solicitante, 
b.nome as servico, 
(select SUM(valorServico) from labservicovalor where idLabServico=c.idLabServico) as valorServico, 
c.idLabPedido, 
f.dente
from
Iabpedido a
inner join labservico b
inner join labpedidoservico c on c.idLabServico = b.id and e.id = c.idLabPedido
inner join usuorios e on (a.usuorioInsert = e.id)
inner join labpedidoservicodente f on (a.id = f.idLabPedido)
where
b.status='1'
order by a.dataCadostro
```

Comment: please add some explanation so the OP understands why this will work and why it wasn't working, read [answer] for writing better answers

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I tried that, still it would return the same value as if it was singular and not the sum of the rows. I believe it can be archieve in the code itself, by multipling the single value for the num_rows, even tho I believe for the matter of performance, this thing solved in the query would be better.